# Send one big packet or many smaller packets for whiteboard app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, canvas, socket.io

I'm making an online whiteboard app with `socket.io` just for fun and learning and I'm trying to decide between these two options for the drawing tool:

1) Wait for around 20 points (or until mouseup) and send that points array all at once over the wire. The effect on the clients will be they will only see line paths updated every 20 or so points.

2) Send each point as soon as it is drawn as a packet. This will result in around 20x more packets being sent but the responsiveness will be immediate on all clients.

I'm not sure which option is better. I'm worried that if I do the second option that the server will be overburdened by all the point packets but ideally it would be better just because it would be so responsive and look so pretty but I'm unsure of how feasible it is considering the quantity of the packets required to be sent back and forth.

Comment: Your worry about overloading the server falls squarely in the realm of premature optimization; a dark and dangerous place.   I would highly recommend trying to go as responsive as possible,  and IF you see massive performance issues, THEN consider throttling.  Particularly since your packets are small.  And your user volume is low.  And it's for fun and learning.  And servers are powerful.  And broadband is ubiquitous.

Comment: Let your design needs determine what your data flow requirements are. The important point in remote synching is that all canvas drawing commands be "atomic". So if you want to draw each point as the user clicks you must `beginPath, moveTo, lineTo, stroke` for each new point. And if you want to draw a completed batch of points you must `beginPath, moveTo, multiple lineTo's, stroke`. So the important point is not to leave your drawing commands hanging -- **don't** start a `beginPath` that is left open between multiple socket events.

Comment: Good points. However, your comment about sockets being unreliable is  incorrect. WebSockets are implemented on top of TCP, not UDP and are therefore 100% reliable (to the chagrin of twitch game developers everywhere) while connected. See,  [WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket), [RFC spec](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455).  However, this reliability does not extend to a client completely dropping the connection itself, which is a different problem entirely.

Comment: @Kal_Torak. Thanks for the info about TCP being the websocket protocol. I stand corrected, TCP is reliable. Can I pick your brain? If a websocket connection is not able to be established, does socket.io fallback to polling (like SignalR does)? And is polling equally reliable?

Comment: Socket.io does indeed fallback to other methods if websockets are not available.  More accurately, and different from SignalR, socket.io actually _starts_ in a "fallback" state of XHR or JSONP, then _upgrades_ to websockets if they are available.  As to reliability, I don't have enough experience to say, as I've only been using it a couple months on my current project.

Answer (score 1):

Even if you send each individual mouse movement, it doesn't necessarily mean that there will be one packet transmitted over the wire for each of those. The WebSocket layer will buffer up the data and then decide when to transmit it.

You are better to just send the data each time you receive a pointer event, for optimum user experience.